# Vanilla JavaScript Form Validation for Multiple Versions of the Same Form

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a form on my site which I validate with some custom JavaScript (see below).  The thing is, I now need to create a second version of the same form in the footer.  The only difference is one of styling, otherwise - they are the exact same form with the same function.

As such, I now need to re-purpose my form so that it can validate both forms, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to do that.

Here is the code that I currently use:

```
const signupForm = document.querySelector('#signup-form')
const signupName = document.querySelector('#signup-form input[name="name"]')
const signupEmail = document.querySelector('#signup-form input[name="email"]')

let validName = false
let validEmail = false

const emailRegex = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/

signupForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  let canSubmit = false

  if (validName === true && validEmail === true) {
    canSubmit = true
  }

  if (canSubmit === false) {
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  checkNameInput()
  checkEmailInput()
})

signupName.addEventListener('blur', () => checkNameInput())
signupEmail.addEventListener('blur', () => checkEmailInput())

function checkNameInput() {
  let nameValue = signupName.value.trim()

  if (nameValue === '' || nameValue == null) {
    setErrorState(signupName, 'Name is required')
  } else {
    validName = true
    setSuccessState(signupName)
  }
}

function checkEmailInput() {
  let emailValue = signupEmail.value.trim()

  if (emailValue === '' || emailValue == null) {
    setErrorState(signupEmail, 'Email is required')
  } else if (!emailRegex.test(emailValue)) {
    setErrorState(signupEmail, 'Please enter a valid email address')
  } else {
    validEmail = true
    setSuccessState(signupEmail)
  }
}

function setErrorState(input, message) {
  const errorDiv = input.nextElementSibling

  input.classList.add('input-error')
  errorDiv.classList.remove('hidden')
  errorDiv.textContent = message
}

function setSuccessState(input) {
  const errorDiv = input.nextElementSibling

  input.classList.remove('input-error')
  errorDiv.classList.add('hidden')
  errorDiv.textContent = ''
}
```

I obviously need to change `querySelector` to `querySelectorAll` and add a `forEach` loop.  And that is exactly what I tried to do -- as follows:

```
const signupForm = document.querySelectorAll('#signup-form')
const signupName = document.querySelectorAll('#signup-form input[name="name"]')
const signupEmail = document.querySelectorAll('#signup-form input[name="email"]')

let validName = false
let validEmail = false

const emailRegex = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/

signupForm.forEach(form => {
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    let canSubmit = false

    if (validName === true && validEmail === true) {
      canSubmit = true
    }

    if (canSubmit === false) {
      e.preventDefault()
    }

    checkNameInput()
    checkEmailInput()
  })
})

signupName.forEach(name => {
  name.addEventListener('blur', () => checkNameInput())
})

signupEmail.forEach(email => {
  email.addEventListener('blur', () => checkEmailInput())
})

function checkNameInput() {
  let nameValue = signupName.value.trim()

  if (nameValue === '' || nameValue == null) {
    setErrorState(signupName, 'Name is required')
  } else {
    validName = true
    setSuccessState(signupName)
  }
}

function checkEmailInput() {
  let emailValue = signupEmail.value.trim()

  if (emailValue === '' || emailValue == null) {
    setErrorState(signupEmail, 'Email is required')
  } else if (!emailRegex.test(emailValue)) {
    setErrorState(signupEmail, 'Please enter a valid email address')
  } else {
    validEmail = true
    setSuccessState(signupEmail)
  }
}

function setErrorState(input, message) {
  const errorDiv = input.nextElementSibling

  input.classList.add('input-error')
  errorDiv.classList.remove('hidden')
  errorDiv.textContent = message
}

function setSuccessState(input) {
  const errorDiv = input.nextElementSibling

  input.classList.remove('input-error')
  errorDiv.classList.add('hidden')
  errorDiv.textContent = ''
}
```

But this does **not** work.  Any idea why not?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Here is the html of the two forms:

```
  // Sidebar Form
  <form class="signup-form sidebar-signup-form dark-form" novalidate>
    <input
      class="sidebar-signup-input"
      name="name"
      placeholder="Name"
      type="text"
    />
    <div class="hidden input-error-text"></div>

    <input
      class="sidebar-signup-input"
      name="email"
      placeholder="Email"
      type="email"
    />
    <div class="hidden input-error-text"></div>
    <button class="sidebar-signup-button" type="submit">Signup Today</button>
  </form>

  // Footer Form
  <form class="signup-form footer-signup-form dark-form" novalidate>
    <input
      class="footer-signup-input"
      name="name"
      placeholder="Name"
      type="text"
    />
    <div class="hidden input-error-text"></div>
    <input
      class="footer-signup-input"
      name="email"
      placeholder="Email"
      type="email"
    />
    <div class="hidden input-error-text"></div>
    <button class="footer-signup-button" type="submit">
      Signup Today
    </button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Define "does not work". Where is the HTML? There is so much to fix here it really should be posted in a code review forum, e.g. multiple elements with the same ID, form controls named "name", `addEventListener('blur', () => checkEmailInput())` instead of `addEventListener('blur', checkEmailInput)`, missing semi–colons, unnecessary globals, etc.

Comment: Does not work means that it does not validate (which it did before) and it does submit (which it wouldn't do before unless it was validated).  In terms of same ID, semicolons, globals) -- I was just trying to figure out how to get the JavaScript validation to work. I plan to fix those things once I get the javascript working (indeed, I already fixed the id).  And I fixed the addEventListener (thanks).

Comment: You're using an ID selector "#signup-form", however that value is used as a class, not ID so use a class selector ".signup-form". Using globals for *validName* and *validEmail* means the two form validations interfere with each other. Form control values are strings, so `emailValue == null` will never be true, nor will `nameValue == null` (since `'' != null`) so just remove that from the test, `== ''` or `nameValue.length == 0` is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  A few notes -- on my computer they are both classes (I should have updated the question to match that).  I'll change the global and remove the null tests.  Once again, thanks.